# Question related to Quadratic Congruences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Is there a solution for $x^2 ≡ 3 (\text{mod } 4)$ ? I don't get the hang of congruences when it comes to quadratic congruences. Need an explanation for how I should interpret it.

Comment: There are only four possibilities.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: They mean that there are only four elements in ${\bf Z}_4$ so you can check any mod-$4$-equation (containing one free variable $x$) by substituting each of those four values for $x$, then you know if it's solveable or not.

Comment: $x^2\equiv 3\mod 4$ is equivalent to $4|x^2-3$ , in genral $a\equiv b\mod n$ is equivlant to $n|a-b$.

Comment: So, if $x^2\equiv a\mod n$, we also have $(x+kn)^2\equiv a\mod n$  , $k\in \mathbb Z$ (Try to verify it with the definition above). Hence, you only have to check the numbers $0,1,2,\cdots ,n-1$. There are powerful theorems to find out whether $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $n$, (meaning that there is an $x$ with $x^2\equiv a\mod n$) becoming necessary if $n$ is very large.

Answer (score 0):

The list of elements is $0,1,2,3$ (or $-1$). The corresponding list of squares is $0,1,0,1$. Thus $3$ is not in the list.